# Aura:If condition's strange functionality?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning, customer-portal, aura

Its really strange behavior from Aura:if statement. 
I am using Aura:if to hide fields from the Lightning component's form based on the Login user.

```
 <aura:if isTrue="{!or(v.user == null, v.user.Name == 'SFDC Comm Guest User')}">
  .....
  .....
 </aura:if>
```

This statement is hiding the fields that fall inside the statement when I first open the page, BUT, when I refresh the page, those fields are like showing up- say half a second and disappearing.

I know the Aura:If statement is getting validated with each refresh on the page, but, this is kind of strange for the end users to see the fields appear and disappear this way. Is there a way/solution for this to not happen?

Comment: Suggest you temporarily always output `{! v.user.Name }` in the component to see if the problem is with that attribute or with the `aura:if`.

Comment: What is the default value of your `v.user` attribute?

Comment: Default value really matters? I am not sure. I have not set any default values for the attribute. `<aura:attribute name="user" type="User"/>`

Answer (score 4):

I would probably try to use the `<aura:If>` statement to conditionally SHOW fields rather than hide them. This way they won't appear and then disappear.

Ie, show the desired fields to users who are not the guest user:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!and(v.user != null, v.user.Name != 'SFDC Comm Guest User')}">
  <!-- fields that you want to only show for valid users -->
  <aura:set attribute="else">
    <!--other fields-->
  </aura:set>
</aura:if>
```

You could also swap the logic and have the guest user as a default so those fields show up by default

```
<aura:attribute name="user" type="User" default="{'Name':'SFDC Comm Guest User'}"/>
```

Comment: This seems good, but, I have this requirement where I need to have fields in an order. The first row(out of four rows) of the fields should be hidden(not shown) when there is an active user accessing the page. And these should be shown when no-active user. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try an else condition - I've added it to my example

Comment: If that doesn't do it... try having a (mostly) empty main body and have your stuff in the else. I don't think it can be totally empty though.

Comment: For an unauthenticated user, I need to show a row of 2 fields on top of the remaining three rows of fields. Does it make sense?
That's the reason, I am trying to hide the top row with Aura:if and show when there is no logged in user.

Comment: The other options is to add the user.Name as SFDC Comm Guest User as a default

Comment: Can I use:
`<aura:if isTrue="{!and(v.user != null, v.user.Name != 'SFDC Comm Guest User')}">
<aura:set attribute="else">
    <!--other fields-->
  </aura:set>
  <!-- fields that you want to only show for valid users -->
</aura:if>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59321/discussion-between-caspar-harmer-and-arnold-jr).

Answer (score 1):

How are you setting the value of `v.user`?

When the page renders the value if `v.user` is null potentially so it may be displayed briefly until the value changes. sometimes it does, and sometimes it does not. depends on browser, order, speed, etc.

Suggest you do the following:

```
<aura:attribute name="showGuestBlock" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
```

Then in your JS, determine if you should show that block and set the attribute to true.

Then

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.showGuestBlock}">
```

Basically to prevent this I default the section to NOT show and then set it to show when appropriate. This prevents the flash of visibility we see at times. Not sure if a bug or not as I would think the renderer runs after init but alas, it is what it is

on a side note, it is better to use `empty(v.user)` than `v.user == null`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm that is interesting. Have you tried CSS? There was a webinar that said aura:if should be used, however, I would see if CSS is actually faster.

Check out the webinar about component efficiency. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Kf_QmYh_4o

It could also be a caching issue.